# BlogEngin.Net:The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I download blogengindotnet and uploaded on my host . but when I want login to admin, I getting thins error :

**Security Exception**

```
Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.
```

> Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the
>   permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

I searched on google but cant any answer.

Can I disable Security in blogengin ?

How can do this error ?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what version of BlogEngine you are using it may require full trust:

https://blogengine.codeplex.com/discussions/544972

You should set up full trust in web.config or if it is impossible on your hosting switch to another version.

Comment: I add `trust level="Full" />` but getting error . i dont use this tag in web.config . what version support this blog?

Comment: What version of BlogEngine are you using?

Comment: I use Latest version .